# Case statement that adds column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I need to write a case statement that will return

```
“1 of 3” if someone voted in one of three elections, 
“2 of 3” if someone voted in two of three elections, 
“3 of 3” if someone voted in three of three elections,
```

The problem is that some of the values are a varchar and some are null and I cannot add them together.
This is my idea but I cannot get it to work.

```
select 
id,
CASE 
     WHEN race1 + race2 + race3 = 0 then '0-3'
     WHEN race1 + race2 + race3 = 1 then '1-3'
     WHEN race1 + race2 + race3 = 2 then '2-3'
     WHEN race1 + race2 + race3 = 3 then '3-3'
     WHEN race1 + race2 + race3 is null then 'Unknown'
 END AS General_Turnout
from test4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cac66/3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
select 
id,
    CAST( (CASE WHEN race1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN race2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN race3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR) + '-3'
AS General_Turnout
from test4
```

Answer (score 0):

use COELESCE(value,0) so that null is taken as zero

Comment: Yes I tried IsNull(race1, 0), on all and that removes the null values and replaces them with 0, but I still cannot add the rest. Thanks

Comment: You can use cast for conversion.I think the example is already given above

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted on SQLfiddle, I assume NULL means *did not vote* and any string means *did vote*. You can't add the non-numeric strings you have in columns race1, race2, and race3, but this should work:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CAST(
    CASE WHEN race1 IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN race2 IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN race3 IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END
  AS CHAR) + '-3' AS General_Turnout
FROM test4
```